# Apache2 not redirecting non-www request to www

Tags: django, apache2

I am trying to redirect my all **non-www** requests to **www**.
Here is my apache config setting.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed `<VirtualHost *:443>` as :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [L,R=301]
 </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now it's working fine.